# Can I have different Application settings (ENV variables) for Azure App Service instances?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

In Azure App Service, I can scale out to more than just 1 server instance.
But I only get 1 central location for setting ENV variables - "Application settings" under "Configuration" in the Azure portal.

This means all my instances get the exact same ENV variables. That's not what I want. Instead, I would like to customize just one (or a few) instances with slightly different ENV variables ("Application settings" as Azure calls them).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, per App Service, you share all the same settings, no matter to how many instances you scale out. You say "this is not what I want" - but it is in fact what basically everybody else wants when scaling out ;)

Your alternative is to use multiple App Services. You can host them on the same App Service Plan, so you share the costs between them.

Comment: My use case for instances with different settings would be to dedicate a few instances for specific tasks. For example, 10 instances only serve web requests, but 2 instances also run background jobs (cron, queue, etc). Since I have a monolithic app, all 12 instances need the exact same code. I guess I could run two apps as you suggested, but I will need the new code deployed to both apps at the same time.

Comment: thats what a proper CI/CD pipeline is for ;)